# Package system in broke in Xubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, update-manager

I have been using Xubuntu 14.04 LTS

Whenever I update my Linux I get a error as per the screenshot. Please help, what should I do ?

Specs:

- Intel Pentium D 3.00GHz
- 2GB RAM
- Gigabyte G41-M Combo

Update error:

[image]

Comment: Please run `sudo apt-get update` from the command and post the results.

Comment: Here are the results - http://i.imgur.com/NAOEoxu.png

Comment: Your picture does not show me the final output after `apt-get update` parses through the sources lists.

Comment: Found my answer here - https://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies

Comment: Read up here for answer - https://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies

Answer (score 0):

The issue could be of some failing repos in your repos list file.

you can follow those steps:

1- go to http://repogen.simplylinux.ch/

2- select your country, select Trusty 14.04 as your release and tick all options in the following (Ubuntu Branches,Ubuntu Updates,Ubuntu Partner Repos,Ubuntu Extras Repos) and click generate at the end of the page.

3- copy all the content in the first text area you see.

4- open terminal and use the command `sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list`

5- empty the file and then paste the copied content from the website into it.

6- hit CTRL + X it will ask you if you want to save and exit, save and exit

7- `sudo apt-get update` and that should solve your problem

if you still have the same problem run `sudo dpkg-reconfigure -a`.